# Prove that $(a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not open.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want to prove myself that a half-interval $(a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is not an open set. I checked it in [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Half-Open_Real_Interval_is_not_Open_Set).

**My proof**: We wish to prove that $b\notin (a,b]^{\circ}$. Assume that $b\in (a,b]^{\circ}$ so there exists a $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(b)=(b-r,b+r)\subseteq (a,b]$. Since, for example, $(b+r)/2\in B_{r}(b)$, but $(b+r)/2\notin (a,b]$, which shows that there in fact doesn't exist a $r>0$ such that $K(b,r)\subseteq (a,b]$. A contradiction.

How's the proof, and is there something that should be corrected/improved?

Comment: You need to get the hypotheses on $M$ straight for a start. Just saying $(M,d)$ is a metric space does not imply that $(a,b]\subset M$.

Comment: Is there some order on $M$? If not then what is the meaning of $(a,b]$? It seems to me that $M=\mathbb R$ in your question. If so then your proof is correct provided that $K(b,r)$ and $B_r(b)$ denote the same set.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich We can call $M:=\mathbb{R}$. I am not implying that $(a,b]$ is a subset of $M$, but assuming that $(a,b]$ is in $M$. Then I want to show that $(a,b]$ is not an open set in $M$. I will keep it in my mind to define the hypothesis better in future.

Comment: I think you mean $b+\frac{r}{2}$, not $\frac{b+r}{2}$.

Comment: I overlooked the mistake that was caught by @BrianTung. Your proof is *almost* correct if $M=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is technically correct but a bit unnecessarily complicated. 
If you mean $\Bbb{R}$ as your metric space, then all you have to do is consider the open ball of center $b$ and radius $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, the ball is not in $(a,b]$ because it contains elements larger than $b$.